# Tried to build an algorithm to certain numbers out of list, it skips numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a script that gives me a list of numbers at one point.
I only need the numbers in between 11 and 88.
This is what I tried, simplified:

```
m = [13, 2, 3, 23, 1]
for x in range(len(m)-1):
    if m[x] < 11 or m[x] > 88:
        del m[x]
print(m)
```

The list that gets printed is `[13, 3, 23]`.

If I print the individual list items that go inside the for loop, I get this output:

```
13
2
23
1
[13, 3, 23]
```

Why does it skip the 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the size of the list at the same time you are iterating through it, that in general is not a good idea. You should instead create a new list with the elements you want.

```
m = [13, 2, 3, 23, 1]
new = []
for i in m:
    if i > 11 and i < 88:
        new.append(i)
print(new)
```

And if you think of the case before
when x was 1 you removed 2 thus the new list was `[13,3,23,1]` so for the next x; `x = 2` `m[x]` was 23 and not 3 as 3 is in index 1 now and that is why 3 was still there.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need:

```
m = [13, 2, 3, 23, 1]

new_m = []
for i in m:
    if i> 11 and i<88:
        new_m.append(i)

print(new_m)
```

Refer [why it is bad idea to remove element from list while iterating](https://www.quora.com/Why-can%E2%80%99t-you-modify-lists-through-for-in-loops-in-Python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m = [13, 2, 3, 23, 1]
newList = [x for x in m if not ((x<11) or (x>88))]
print (newList)

Output: [13,23]
```

Comment: the output incorrect. your output should be [2,3,1] and it is not he want

Answer (score 0):

One liner to do this using for comprehension

```
m = [x for x in m if 11 <= x <= 88]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use same array to in a loop, if you delete the value the array size will change. To avoid that, you can use While Loop to do on that.

Below script 
Time O(n) SPace O(1)

```
m = [13, 2, 3, 23, 1]
i=0
while i < len(m):
  if m[i] < 11 or m[i] > 88:
    del m[i]
  else:
    i+=1
print(m)
```